# Audio chunk distribution issue in Python based multi-client voice chat with 2 simultaneous speakers

Tags: python, voip, python-multithreading

I'm working on a Python based multi-client voice chat application (learning project). While voice transfer between 2 clients works like a charm and the server is also able to handle multiple connections, problems start as soon as 2 persons talk simultaneously. Whenever a client sends audio data (e.g. "AAAA"), while another client is sending "BBBB" the third clients receives something like "ABABABAB".

I've already tried to spawn multiple threads for each user and let a Mutex take control over the clients[] array (the latter one was either implemented wrong or a stupid idea since it doesn't change anything)
I've also included RMS (only send data while somebody is speaking) in order to stop the constant data stream from every connected client, which took a bit of heat from the server and helped a little bit without solving the real problem.

```py
from socket import *
from threading import Thread, Lock

class entry_thread (Thread):

    def __init__(self, host, port):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        adress_voice = (host, port)
        self.voice_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        self.voice_socket.bind(adress_voice)
        self.voice_socket.listen(10)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            sock_v, data_v = self.voice_socket.accept()
            thread = handle_client_thread(sock_v, data_v)
            thread.start()

class handle_client_thread (Thread):

    def __init__(self, vsock, vdata):
        global clients
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.chunk = 1024
        self.vsock = vsock
        self.vdata = vdata
        self.name = self.vsock.recv(1024).decode()
        clients[self.name] = [self.vdata, self.vsock]

    def run(self):
        global clients
        while True:
            try:
                audio_data = self.vsock.recv(self.chunk)
                for x, client in clients.items():
                    if thread_safe:
                        mutex.acquire()
                    try:
                        if (client[0][1] != self.vdata[1]):   #if receipient
                                                              #      != sender
                            client[1].send(audio_data)
                    finally:
                        if thread_safe:
                            mutex.release()
            except:
                break
mutex = Lock()
thread_safe = False
clients = {}
server = entry_thread('', 20003)
server.start()
server.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by putting the whole for-loop into the mutex, while giving each user an individual audio channel within the client.